# To praise: how to build a phrase using this word

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, verbs, adverbs

Would your native speakers' ears feel uncomfortable and confused if I said:

> "to praise ***in*** beautiful words"

instead of

> "to priase ***using*** beautiful words"

Comment: I agree with and have upvoted BobRodes's answer and Choirbean's answer. And just to throw a curveball at you, if it had been, "to praise in such beautiful language," when we want language to mean "style," I would be OK with "in" here.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang There are plenty of curveballs where prepositions are concerned.  :)  I would probably use "in" in the case you mention as well.

Answer (score 1):

Would we be confused?  Probably not, but it might depend on the context.  That said, we might be more likely to use the preposition *with*, and we would usually name the object of the praise:

*"Our job here is to praise God with beautiful words," said the Pastor, "not because our beautiful words move God, but because they move us."*

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are always difficult to learn, because their use is highly idiomatic.  Although I might say "to praise in beautiful words," I would be more likely to say "to praise with beautiful words."  I would be less likely to use "using" in this context.

(While I'm writing this, Choirbean has posted a similar answer.)

On the other hand, I would say that *in* is more common here:

> He praised our work in a beautiful speech.

The idea of *in* here is that the praise is contained *in* the speech, while we are less likely to think that the praise would be contained in the words.  In that case, the words would be used to praise.

But then, we have this:

> One may find in beautiful words a comfort in troubled times.

Using *with beautiful words* here would be unusual at best, and hard to understand. Probably, in this case we think more of the emotions that the words evoke, and therefore think of those emotions as being *in* the words.  However, that's speculative.  Reasons we use one preposition over another in a given context usually are.

Comment: My answer might be similar, but yours is better :)  I had to struggle a bit to find a context where *with beautiful words* was the appropriate formation.

Comment: Well, you found one, and I didn't.  :)